# how can I know the parameters from windbg stack trace

Tags: c#, windbg

For example, the stack looks like below:

```
RetAddr           : Args to Child                                                           : Call Site
000007fe`fda210dc : 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 : ntdll!ZwWaitForSingleObject+0xa
000007fe`ec3d1c87 : 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000340 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000340 : KERNELBASE!WaitForSingleObjectEx+0x79
000007fe`ec3d1c30 : 00000000`00000000 00000000`02530de0 00000000`01025e50 00000000`0302c280 : clr!Thread::LeaveRuntimeNoThrow+0x7c
000007fe`ec3d1ae3 : 00000000`c00000bb 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000058 000007fe`fda2393d : clr!Thread::LeaveRuntimeNoThrow+0xe4
000007fe`ec44088e : 00000000`056a9cf8 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 000007fe`ec435fbb : clr!CLREvent::WaitEx+0x5e
000007fe`ec44079a : 00000000`00000004 000007fe`eff75b35 00000000`c00000bb 00000000`00000000 : clr!SVR::GCHeap::WaitUntilGCComplete+0x2b
000007fe`ec52f455 : 00000000`02530de0 00000000`00000001 00000000`023f8130 00000001`5f758e68 : clr!Thread::RareDisablePreemptiveGC+0x1e2
000007fe`ec3ccffc : 000007ff`008098fa 00000000`0302c5b0 00000000`00000001 00000000`00000000 : clr!AllocateArrayEx+0x5e5
000007fe`eff6d4dd : 000007ff`008098fa 00000000`00000004 00000006`808aff60 00000000`00000004 : clr!JIT_NewArr1+0x45c
000007fe`eff662ea : 00000002`726d4510 00000001`125888f8 00000000`d0947070 00000000`0001f539 : mscorlib_ni!System.Collections.Generic.List`1[[System.__Canon, mscorlib]].set_Capacity(Int32)+0x5d
000007ff`00b57d45 : 00000001`1f720488 08d106e6`26d9c000 00000001`5f749a00 00000000`0302c838 : mscorlib_ni!System.Collections.Generic.List`1[[System.__Canon, mscorlib]].Add(System.__Canon)+0x4a
```

How can i know the parameter (that is, the size) set to set_Capacity? Thanks.

```
000007fe`eff662ea : 00000002`726d4510 00000001`125888f8 00000000`d0947070 00000000`0001f539 : mscorlib_ni!System.Collections.Generic.List`1[[System.__Canon, mscorlib]].set_Capacity(Int32)+0x5d
```

I only backup the windbg console log, but unfortunately lost the dump file.

Comment: It looks like managed code. More specifically, .Net 4 or greater. First, check the version of clr with the command lmv m clr. Then load the corresponding version of sos with .load c:\[path]\sos.dll. If you're sure about the version, you may also try .loadby sos clr. Then do a !clrstack -p. Note that if this is a release build, methods may have been optimized or inlined in a way that it not too easy to retrieve parameter information.

Comment: The issue happened several days ago and unfortunately the dump file was lost. We only saved the windbg console log before the machine restarted.

Comment: Assuming the call stack is correct and not corrupt you would have to look up function signature for `set_capacity` and try to match them, if you're lucky the parameters are not handles/references/pointers and are valid integer values, looking at your arguments though this seems unlikely as all the values are huge apart from `1f539` which is `128313` so I think you are out of luck if you don't have the dump file anymore

Comment: On x64 the first four args are passed in registers rcx, rdx, r8, and r9 so this stack trace doesn't help determine the args.

Comment: I find an approach: create a property set method like set { _aInt = value; Thread.Sleep(10000000); }, and then get the call trace info at the normal run time to see which register stores the parameter. For example, when I call property = 12 and call trace tells the second register stores 12, then can I make the conclusion that the second register is used to store set(int) method's parameter?